# How to Add Sound on the Toggle button?

Tags: android, audio, android-activity, togglebutton

I implement a Toggle Botton on Activity. I wanted to add Sound (on & off) to that button but I am not able to add sound on it.

This is the code I wrote.

```
public class SoundLayout extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
Button soundBttnOn;
private String _showText;


@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.sound_layout);

/** Fetched from the MAIN ACTIVITY */
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle!=null){
    _showText = bundle.getString("button_click");
}
Log.i("btnClick","button clicked is :"+_showText);
soundBttnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.togglebutton);
soundBttnOn.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override

public void onClick(View view) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
/** make a refernce to store the intent when the view has been clicked*/
Intent intent;  
/** Make cases according to the number of buttons you have in screen
 * In this case, I've added one.*/
switch(view.getId()){

case R.id.togglebutton :
    Log.i("btnClick","Result button is clicked whose id is :"+view.getId());
    /** Intent should be fired from this activity to the other activity*/
    intent = new Intent(SoundLayout.this, Main.class);

    /** Start the intent
     * startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();*/

    break;
}
}

}
```

Here I tried to add Sound on toggle button, but I am not able to add sound function on it. So when I click on 'sound on', it gets activated and when I click on 'sound off', it gets deactivated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of setOnCheckedChangeListener of toggle button.In this u get a paramater indicating if the button is in on or off state.Based on it u can play hte required sound using media player.

```
ToggleButton tb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    tb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked)
                System.out.println("ischecked>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.");
            else
                System.out.println("not checked>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>.");

        }
    });
```

Comment: i thinkso u have to use a toggle button instead of a button.In ut code soundButton is of type Button.Change it to toggle button and then check.

Answer (score 2):

Just place the sound file in /res/raw (after creating the folder) and then use MediaPlayer to init, start and then stop playing the sound.

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.AudioFile1); mp.start();
```

And then you get all the start/stop/reset/pause/release methods from mp.

Comment: I Used this code to my Activity but i am still not getting the sound.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void togglesound(View v) {
    int play;
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) v).isChecked();

    if (on) {
        play = 1;
        // Enable sound
        if (play == 1) {
            cleanUpMediaPlayer();
            Vibrator vibe = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            vibe.vibrate(10000);//TIME TO VIBRATE

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.musicmachine);

            mp.start();
        } else {
            play = 0;
            // Disable sound
            stopMediaPlayer();

        }

    }


}
// Cleans MediaPlayer 
public void cleanUpMediaPlayer() {
    if (mp != null) {
        try {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(Displayone.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopMediaPlayer();
}

public void stopMediaPlayer()
{
    mp.stop();
}
```

Comment: try this code and put your sound file in raw folder...its working 100%